# How to return results from a subquery greater than a value

Tags: sql, subquery, expression

I'm trying to find measuring component ids that show up at least 3 times. At this time it is throwing the Oracle Error "ORA-00936: missing expression." I have tried putting in an existing statement to possibly satisfy the missing expression error, to no avail. It either returned too many values or didn't bring back any values at all. How do I fix it to bring back results where my measuring component column brings back values that occur at least 3 times.

```
select td.td_entry_id, td.complete_dttm, imd.init_msrmt_data_id, imd.measr_comp_id,
imd.bus_obj_cd, imd.bo_status_cd, imd.status_upd_dttm, rep.last_name FROM
ci_td_entry td,
ci_td_drlkey drill,
d1_init_msrmt_data imd,
sc_user rep
WHERE td.td_type_cd ='D1-IMDTD'
and td.entry_status_flg = 'C'
and imd.init_msrmt_data_id = drill.key_value
and td.td_entry_id = drill.td_entry_id
and imd.bo_status_cd in ('DISCARDED','REMOVED')
and td.complete_user_id = rep.user_id
and td.complete_dttm >= '01-MAY-21'
and (select count(*)
    from d1_init_msrmt_data imd
    group by imd.measr_comp_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3);
```

Comment: `and (subquery)` is not an expression. `and (subquery)` ... *what*? `and (subquery) >= 1` would be an expression.

Comment: your query would be easier to follow if you used modern (ie only the standard for the last 30 years) SQL-92 join syntax. `exists` would seem to be the way to go, so show how you tried this.

Comment: @Tomalak I tried having the > 3 value on the outside of the query before which resulted in error. It gives "ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row" which didn't make sense to me with being rather new to SQL. I thought if it was an aggregate function like the count clause it would be okay to use in the sub query and not give that error. The following is how I structured the change:                      
    and (select count(*)
    from d1_init_msrmt_data imd
    group by imd.measr_comp_id) > 3

Comment: The error would be because you are grouping in your sub-query which will return a count for each measr_comp_id where there are more than 3, which is not allowed, the sub query must return a single value not a set. Exists is what you want, with the sub query being correlated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original query works using the group by and having function once you add in the expression exists. What needed to be done to have the subquery actually work though was to correlate it to the main query. This was done by adding in the date parameter found in the main query, the parameter looking for "discarded and removed" and also by creating an inner join in the sub query itself, which joined the table used in the sub query to the table in the main query. The final result looked like this:

```
SELECT
    td.td_entry_id,
    td.complete_dttm,
    imd.init_msrmt_data_id,
    imd.measr_comp_id,
    imd.bus_obj_cd,
    imd.bo_status_cd,
    imd.status_upd_dttm,
    rep.last_name
FROM
    ci_td_entry          td,
    ci_td_drlkey         drill,
    d1_init_msrmt_data   imd,
    sc_user              rep
WHERE
    td.td_type_cd = 'D1-IMDTD'
    AND td.entry_status_flg = 'C'
    AND imd.init_msrmt_data_id = drill.key_value
    AND td.td_entry_id = drill.td_entry_id
    AND td.complete_dttm = imd.status_upd_dttm
    AND imd.bo_status_cd IN (
        'DISCARDED',
        'REMOVE'
    )
    AND td.complete_user_id = rep.user_id
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            d1_init_msrmt_data imd2
        WHERE
            imd.measr_comp_id = imd2.measr_comp_id
            AND imd2.status_upd_dttm >= '01-JUN-21'
            AND imd2.bo_status_cd IN (
                'DISCARDED',
                'REMOVE'
            )
        GROUP BY
            imd2.measr_comp_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) >= 3
    );
```

I appreciate everyone's help in getting this result.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I bring back results where my measuring component column brings back values that occur at least 3 times.

I *guess* this is what you're asking?

```sql
SELECT
    td.td_entry_id,
    td.complete_dttm,
    imd.init_msrmt_data_id,
    imd.measr_comp_id,
    imd.bus_obj_cd,
    imd.bo_status_cd,
    imd.status_upd_dttm,
    rep.last_name
FROM
    ci_td_entry                      td
    INNER JOIN ci_td_drlkey       drill ON drill.td_entry_id = td.td_entry_id
    INNER JOIN d1_init_msrmt_data   imd ON imd.init_msrmt_data_id = drill.key_value
    INNER JOIN sc_user              rep ON rep.user_id = td.complete_user_id
WHERE
    td.td_type_cd ='D1-IMDTD'
    AND td.entry_status_flg = 'C'
    AND imd.bo_status_cd in ('DISCARDED','REMOVED')
    AND td.complete_dttm >= '01-MAY-21'
    AND (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM d1_init_msrmt_data
        WHERE measr_comp_id = imd.measr_comp_id
    ) >= 3
;
```

*"All records for which the same `measr_comp_id` occurs at least 3 times in `d1_init_msrmt_data`."*

Comment: Although that returned values, it didn't take out measurement IDs that show up less than 3 times. I found one that only shows up twice, which would not be wanted in this query. I ran into this issue when I tried creating the exist statement to satisfy the missing expression, it did not take out values that occur less than 3 times. Apologies if my info isn't the greatest or most clarifying, I am rather new to the SQL world and stackoverflow

Comment: I believe I tried something similar to what you tried above. Using an inner join in the subquery itself but the results were the same to what I just wrote about above. That is when I started using the group by and having clause which by itself works great as a standalone query. But the query needs more info and parameters so I created that subquery but just can't get it to go mainly due to the expression error.

Comment: @The_Analyst It's hard to say without seeing the data. The above query definitely should not return any rows where the correlated subquery returns values less than 3. You can double-check by copying the subquery to the select list and seeing for yourself what it returns for each row.

Comment: First off I appreciate your time and understanding here. When I run it by itself it seems to give an overall count of all measuring component IDs at 1,682,794 instead of counts per measuring component ID. So if we had the > 3 parameter like the query above does than it will pull back all results since the count is greater than 3. I further tested by changing to value from > 3 to > 1,682,794 and it didn't return anything which shows it isn't breaking down by measuring component ID

Comment: @The_Analyst I don't think you have correlated the subquery. You need to make a reference to a value from the main query for this to work. That's what `WHERE measr_comp_id = imd.measr_comp_id` does. Note that in the subquery above, there is no table alias. `imd` refers to the main query.